# Foundation 5 with Sass - which files do i need to upload to my website?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

```
I'm using Compass to compile locally with the standard Foundation 5 bower files.
```

I have installed Wordpress and am running the foundationpress theme.

When i make changes to the foundation.css file via _settings.scss using Compass, will i then need to update just the foundation.css file within the foundationpress theme or also all the SCSS files as well?

Comment: Try it and find out?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice! i just uploaded the app.css file in the style.css folder and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have to update the compiled .css file that you have made.

Comment: Thanks! Would you recommend stripping out all the scss and sass framework files from the main theme folder?

Comment: I still upload those files every once in a while so I can access them from another computer via FTP. It's always idea to have another copy